# How to differentiate an integral on Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am so new on Mathematica. I  try to find the first variation of this function according to $t$ on mathematica but I could not achieve.
Here is the function ;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}u\left(c\left(t\right)\right)\exp\left\{ -\int_{0}^{t}\theta\left(c\left(s\right)\text{d}s\right)\right\} \text{d}t$$

How can I find the first variation of this integral according to $t$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation? 
The variable `t` is only a dummy variable, that expression is not a function of `t`. Therefore its derivative is zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you write your integral using [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html)

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, t}]
```

> [image: Integral]

And the derivatives using [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html)

```
D[g[x], x]
```

> ```
> g'[x]
> ```

To differentiate the integral you can write

```
D[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, t}], t]
```

> ```
> f[t]
> ```

In your case

```
D[Integrate[ u[c[t]] Exp[-Integrate[th[c[s]], {s, 0, t}]], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}], t]
```

> 0

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to Inactivate Integrate so that you can perform the derivative without needlessly trying to evaluate a slow symbolic integral.